# pThreads on Win 7 and Win10

Tags: php, windows, xampp, pthreads

I can't install/add pthreads to my Win7 and Win10 xampp. 
I downloaded the release:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/

unpacked the extension dll (php_pthreads.dll) to extension directory and the runtime dll (pthreadVC2.dll) to php directory (same dir as php.exe) and add extension=php_pthreads.dll to my configuration, but still it doesn't work.

What to do?

Thanks for the answer.

Nebojša

Answer (score 0):

Windows supporting threads at all would be news to me. The P in pthreads stands for POSIX, like Unix.

This is a different direction, but perhaps the Windows Subsystem for Linux would be worth investigating. It is supposed to provide a basic degree of POSIX compatibility to a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

First,

Did you restart Apache after adding the module ?
If not, you should do it.

Next,
Try the basic php multithreaded program

```
<?php
class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
  public function __construct($arg){
    $this->arg = $arg;
  }

  public function run(){
    if($this->arg){
      printf("Hello %s\n", $this->arg);
    }
  }
}
$thread = new AsyncOperation("World");
if($thread->start())
  $thread->join();
?>
```

You seem to have followed all the necessary steps. Should be straightforward from there.

Comment: Solved! First mistake was a wrong version of pthreads, and second I didn't  put pthreadVC2.dll to the 'C:\windows\system32' directory. 
You may find good tutorial here: http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php